# jqgrid column drag-drop ,dropping only the column header not the column data

Tags: jqgrid

Jqgrid column drag and drop is not working properly if more than one column is having the same name.
In such case it drag and drops only the column header not the acutal coulmn data.

Help me to fix this issue.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Column names: the `name` property in the `colModel` *must be unique* and can't contain any special characters like spaces or points. The values from the `colNames` array do can have duplicate and can contain free text.

Only the texts from `colNames` see the user. `name` properties of the `colModel` are used for *internal* purposes.